# Выборка значений из 2-х таблиц

Tags: mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с запросом:

Есть таблица brands, в которой хранятся поля brand_id, parent_id и brand_name. В ней находятся как родители бренда, так и их дети.

Есть таблица goods, в которой хранятся поля goods_brandid и brand_sort. То есть, goods_brandid = brand_id из базы brands.

Собственно сам вопрос, как вытащить все brand_sort из таблицы goods, где их parent_id = 3, например?

Пробовал вытащить вот так, но все равно выводит все значения:

```
SELECT goods.brand_sort, brands.parent_id FROM goods, brands WHERE brands.parent_id = '3'
```

**Обновление**

Спасибо всем огромное, сделал немножко по-другому:

```
SELECT goods.brand_sort FROM goods
LEFT JOIN brands ON (brands.brand_id = goods.goods_brandid)
WHERE brands.parent_id = '3' GROUP BY `brand_sort` ;)
```

Comment: А как ты джойнишь таблицы? ;-)

Comment: Вот именно JOIN и не понимаю)

Answer (score 1):

Добавь: `AND goods.goods_brandid = brands.brand_id`

**Обновление**

Попробуйте так.

```
SELECT
  goods.brand_sort, brands.parent_id
FROM
  goods, brands
WHERE
  brands.parent_id = '3' AND
  goods.goods_brandid = brands.brand_id
```

Comment: Не работает :( Ещё и копирует значение по 5-7 раз

Answer (score 1):

ответ из вопроса:

---

сделал немножко по-другому:

```
SELECT goods.brand_sort FROM goods
LEFT JOIN brands ON (brands.brand_id = goods.goods_brandid)
WHERE brands.parent_id = '3' GROUP BY goods.brand_sort
```